# c++ copy constructon bugs when static declaration

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with an error related to the copie construction in C++. Here is a code illustrating my question:

```
//File MYString.h
#ifndef __MYSTRING_H__
#define __MYSTRING_H__

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MYString
{
  private:
    char * m_ptr; 
    void allocation(int);
    int m_lg;  

  public: 

    MYString ();
    MYString (const char * );
    ~MYString ();
    MYString(const String & );
};
#endif

//File MYString.cpp
#include "MYString.h"


MYString::MYString ()
{
    m_ptr= NULL;
    m_lg=0;
    allocation (1);         
    m_ptr[0]='\0';
}

void MYString::allocation(int a)
{  
  delete m_ptr;
  m_lg=a;
  m_ptr=new char[m_lg];
}

MYString ::MYString (const char * str)
{
    m_ptr = NULL;
    allocation ( strlen(str)+1 );
    strcpy ( m_ptr, str );
}


//copy constructor
MYString::MYString(const MYString & str) 
{
      allocation(str.m_lg);
      strcpy(m_ptr,str.m_ptr);
}


MYString :: ~MYString()
{
  delete m_ptr;
}


//File main.cpp
#include <MYString.h"
int main()
{ 
    MYString chaine0("Toto");
    MYString chaine1(chaine1); //ERROR free(): invalid size
                               //Abandon (core dumped)

    //However, this works fine
     //MYString * chaine0 = new String("Toto");
     //MYString *chaine0= new String(chaine0);


    return 0;

}
```

I'm getting an error when I execute the gererated exec : 
//ERROR free(): invalid size
//Abandon (core dumped)

However, when I use the dynamic writing as explained in the main.cpp, this works fine.

Any explanations ?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problems, but all symbols starting with double underscore (e.g. `__MYSTRING_H__`) are reserved in all scoped. See e.g. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information.

Comment: As for your problem: `new[]` needs to be matched by `delete[]`. Otherwise you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `#include <MYString.h"` is not pre-processor friendly. I'm sure some accepts it, but others won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MYString::MYString(const MYString & str)
```

calls

```
allocation(str.m_lg);
```

which calls

```
delete m_ptr;
```

which - at this point - is still unassigned. Its value is *indeterminate*, trying to delete it causes *undefined behavior*. (Which is bad.)

(Another problem here is that you call `delete` for a pointer that - if allocated - is allocated with `new`. Also undefined behavior. If you allocate with `new[]`, use `delete[]`!)

---

A quick fix, that arguably makes a good habit: initialize all POD values in the class declaration:

```
class MYString
{
  private:
    char * m_ptr = nullptr;
    int m_lg = 0;
    ...
```

**However**, while this would have prevented your problem at this point, you need to learn to anticipate such problems.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: I actually agree that a modern book / tutorial should move this to "Appendix B: Advanced Capabilities", but I'm also trying to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `void allocation(int)`, you can implement all your other constructors in terms of `MYString (int, const char *)`, and allocate in the member initialiser. This ensures `m_ptr` is always a valid pointer.

Note that `new[]` is paired with `delete[]`, not `delete`

```
class MYString
{
  private:
    int m_lg;  
    char * m_ptr; 
    MYString (int, const char *);

  public: 
    MYString ();
    MYString (const char *);
    ~MYString ();
    MYString (const String & );
};

MYString::MYString (int lg, const char * str)
 : m_lg(lg), m_ptr(new char[lg])
{
    strcpy ( m_ptr, str );
}

MYString::MYString()
 : MYString(1, "")
{}

MYString::MYString (const char * str)
 : MYString(strlen(str) + 1, str)
{}

MYString::MYString(const String & other) 
 : MYString(other.m_lg, other.m_ptr) 
{}

MYString::~MYString()
{
    delete [] m_ptr;
}
```